# VS2015 class not building .dll

Tags: c#, dll, build, output

This is essentially identical to [Class Library Project File not compiling into .dll or debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880499/class-library-project-file-not-compiling-into-dll-or-debugging), but that item was from 2009 and should be closed and inactive by now.

I, too, have a class solution/project that should be producing a .dll on successful build and isn't.

I have followed all instructions in the previously referenced stack overflow item to no avail.  It doesn't matter if I clean the build, build debug or release versions.  There are no errors, no warnings, and no messages whatsoever.

The Build always succeeds.  If I do a Clean it always succeeds.

The Output path is correct.

How do I get around this issue and get output from the Build?

I'm pretty much at my wits end.  Any thoughts or suggestions?  This is VS 2015, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 running on Windows 10 Pro.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I'm a screw-up!  Sometimes you have to get frustrated to find the real problem...

If you have this problem, one suggestion would be to verify that you really loaded the solution/project from the location on the (a) hard drive that corresponds to the one you are trying to reference in another solution.  Be careful when doing so, sometimes those "Recent" solutions aren't really what you think they are.

Sorry to clog space up with such a stupid issue.  It's getting late; I must be getting a little tired.